# Can `Ctrl-x` in emacs can be changed to `Ctrl-w`?

Tags: emacs

I'm newbie for emacs and i want to change `Ctrl-x` key to the `Ctrl-w`.

Is it easy to change? if so, how could I change?

(also, if i want to split buffer vertically (C-x + 3) to (C-w + v), how should i write my .emacs?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is don't do it.  You're fighting a strong convention, and you'll probably be playing whack-a-mole with edge cases.

That said, you can get 95% there with:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-w") ctl-x-map)
```

Split vertically can be changed with:

```
(define-key ctl-x-map (kbd "v") #'split-window-right)
```

Note that these just override the `C-w` and `C-w v` key binds.  Existing `C-x` keybinds (except `C-x v`) are unchanged.